# How to get the right binding?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I do not get the right tick-binding for the following scope. The tick.scope shout have the top-declared vars.
For better understanding here is a fiddle:[myFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AK8Ru/2/)

```
 ole.prototype = {
    TILE_SIZE: 480,
    DEST_WIDTH: 1920,
    init: function () {
        console.log("test1: ", this.TILE_SIZE);
        //document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', ??????.bind(this.onMouseMove, this)),
        this.tick();
        $(window).on('anim_frame', ?????.bind(this.tick, this))
    },
    tick: function () {
       console.log("test2: ", this.TILE_SIZE);
       console.log("tick done once: DEST_WIDTH: ",this.DEST_WIDTH);          
       zaehler++;  
       console.log("ticker tick: ",zaehler);            

    },
```

Comment: If you are not sure how `.bind` (or any function) works, I recommend to read the MDN documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change

```
$(window).on('anim_frame', ?????.bind(this.tick, this))
```

to

```
$(window).on('anim_frame', this.tick.bind(this))
```

**See Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/AK8Ru/3/